# Checking if there is an incoming socket

Tags: java, sockets, connection

Im creating a server for my game but this question is more java related. So i want to check of their is an incomming socket but i still want to run the game becouse the server is hosted by an user and not seperate by an external program. But still i want to check if someone is connection using an socket. What i now have is:

```
    public void updateConnection() throws IOException {


    Socket connection = server.accept();

    System.out.println("Ape is connecting");

    ServerClient client = new ServerClient(connection);

    clientsWaiting.add(client);

}
```

I want this method to be used every frame and not continuously checking if thats  posible. If it isn't posible what else shall i use to create my server and check if some ones connecting each frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best bet would be to have your game check for incoming socket connections in a separate thread.  You could create a `Runnable` that just listens for connections continuously.

When you check for an incoming connection: `Socket connection = server.accept();`, what is actually happening is you are placing a block on that particular thread until you receive a connection.  This will cause your code to stop executing.  The only way around this is parallelization.  You can handle all of your networking tasks on one thread, whilst handling your gaming logic and rendering on another.

Be aware though, writing code to be run on multiple threads has many pit falls.  Java provides some tools to minimize the potential problems, but it is up to you, the programmer, to ensure that your code will be thread safe.  Going into detail about the many concerns regarding parallel programming is beyond the scope of this question. I suggest that you do a bit of research on it, because bugs that arise from this type of programming are sometimes hard to reproduce and to track.

Now that I have given you this disclaimer, to use `Runnable` to accomplish what you are trying to do, you could do something similar to this:

```
Runnable networkListener = () -> {
    //declare and instantiate server here
    while(true){
         Socket connection = server.accept();
         //whatever you would like to do with the connection would go here
    }
}
Thread networkThread = new Thread(networkListener);
networkThread.start();
```

You would place that before your game loop and it would spawn a thread that would listen for connections without interrupting your game.  There are a lot of good idioms out there on how to handle `Socket`s using `ThreadPool`s to track them, spawning a new `Thread` each time a new connection is made, so I suggest you do some research on that as well.

Good luck to you, this isn't an easy road you are about to venture down.

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: and this runnable i can start any time i want??

Comment: Yes, but you should only start it once in your program.  It will continue to run throughout the entire execution of your program.

Answer (score 1):

One more addition: when you establish TCP connection you are not dealing with frames(UDP is frame based protocol), you are dealing with stream of bytes.
The lower lever Byteoutpustream example:

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();  

// read from the stream  
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
byte[] content = new byte[ 2048 ];  
int bytesRead = -1;  
while( ( bytesRead = inputStream.read( content ) ) != -1 ) {  
    baos.write( content, 0, bytesRead );  
} // while
```

So when client finishes writing, but stream is still open, your read method blocks. If you expect certain data from client, you read it and then call your print method or however you want to notify, etc...